# Swift: what is the right way to merge the [[[CGFloat]]] to [[CGFloat]] with extra data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a CGFloat array like

```
[[[1,2],[2,3]],[[6,1],[5,6]],[[6,1],[11,6],[21,3]]]
```

No I want to merge the subarray and add the array data in each sub array like

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[9999,9999],[6,1],[5,6],[9999,9999],[6,1],[11,6],[21,3]]
```

Now I can use `for circulation` and run `beforearray + array[i] + [9999,9999]` in it to achieve the function ,but I want to know the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like:

```
let foo = [[[1,2],[2,3]],[[6,1],[5,6]],[[6,1],[11,6],[21,3]]]

let bar = foo.joinWithSeparator([[9999,9999]]).map({$0})

print(bar)

// [[1, 2], [2, 3], [9999, 9999], [6, 1], [5, 6], [9999, 9999], [6, 1], [11, 6], [21, 3]]
```

> `joinWithSeparator` returns a view, whose elements are the result of interposing a given `separator` between the elements of the sequence `self`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use special array operator like `filter` since the second array isn't of the same type of the first one.

A simple loop can be sufficient here :

```
let originalTab:[[[CGFloat]]]  = [[[1,2],[2,3]],[[6,1],[5,6]],[[6,1],
var newTab:[[CGFloat]] = []

for subArray in originalTab {
    newTab.appendContentsOf(subArray)
    newTab.append([9999, 9999])
}
```